# Digital signature man in the middle attack prevention

Tags: cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, client-certificates, man-in-the-middle

I have client-side generated a digital signature(JavaScript). The signature is then verified on Java back end. To verify the signature I am passing to the backend - (signature value, public key and message for verification). So far so good, but then the question arises - What if someone performs a man in the middle attack? He can easily generate a signature and send his - (signature value, public key and message.). So in a sense, this makes my current implementation not secure enough.

How can I avoid this? As far as I researched I have to verify that the public key sent is coming from the appropriate client and this is done through CA (Certificate Authority). However, in my case, I am doing this as a final project in university and I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Should I generate the public key certificate on the client side and send them along with the public key? Is it possible to generate self-signed-certificates on client-side and then verify it on the back-end?

Comment: So you're asking how to be sure if this public key really comes from your client, right?

Comment: Now before this verification takes place, how do you decide any request to the server is from an authorized client? Is client required to signup in the first place to qualify as a authorized party?

Comment: There must be some discrimination rules, otherwise I might as well argue a man in middle is also valid client, you have no way to tell.

Comment: @hackape Yes, I am asking how to be sure that the public key comes from my client. What do you mean by discrimination rules?

Comment: @hackape Is SSL/TLS secure enough to prevent man in the middle?

Comment: Yes SSL/TLS is enough to prevent MITM.

Comment: By "discrimination rules", I mean, you need extra information to ensure the other party is trustworthy. Like with SSL certificate, anyone can issue self-signed certificate, but how do you tell which certificate is trustworthy? You set a rule, trusting only those signed by CA. Likewise, 3 clients send request to your server, one of them is MITM'ed, how do you tell? You give away to your clients something inaccessible to the MITM beforehand, a shared secret.

Comment: The point is, to prevent MITM, there must be sth exchange beforehand in a trusted manner. In the SSL/TLS example, a whitelist of trusted CA is exchange beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if someone performs a man in the middle attack

A MITM could replace the signature and the public key

> How can I avoid this?

Mainly use SSL/TLS and/or...

> As far as I researched I have to verify that the public key sent is coming from the appropriate client and this is done through CA (Certificate Authority)

If you use a Certificate Authority, each certificate is signed with the private key of the root CA certificate (or a subCA), so a MITM  can not create a valid certificate because he does not own the root private key.

At server side, you can validate that the signature has been performed with a private key that corresponds to a certificate issued by the CA. Note  that in this case you are working with certificates, not just with public keys ( a certificate envelopes a public key).

> I am doing this as a final project in university and I am not sure how to approach this problem.

You have explained your solution but not the background. I mean why do you decided you need a digital signature? without that information I can not advise you.

> Should I generate the public key certificate on the client side and send them along with the public key?

Read my previous comment

> Is it possible to generate self-signed-certificates on client-side and then verify it on the back-end?

Yes, of course. You can generate a key pair at client side and associate the public key with the user's account during the registration process (using a secure channel)

This way you do not even need a password. The digital signature with the private key is the authentication proof. Using a CA is optional. The CA could issue a certificate containing the public key, but fot this scenario is not required

Comment: Can you point me to some good sources about how can I implement self-signed certificates on the client side?

Comment: Start from the beginning reading about PKI (public key infraestructure) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure and take a look to W3C Web Authentication Api https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn

Comment: @Ne7WoRK,  is your question closed? Do you need additional clarifications?